# What is the best format to store the EMG signals

Tags: python, matlab, myo

I am working with Myo Armband, I am getting live EMG with python and MATLAB. Now I want to store it so that I can use to classify them when I get the same EMG again.
Raw EMG return value from -128 to 127 (8-bit value).

My question is, what is a good format to save the EMG signal and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can save them in .dat, you can use simple load in Matlab or python language.
Physionet uses this file format:
https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/emgdb/

Answer (score -1):

If you have a large amount of data, I would suggest HDF5 because it is designed for exactly that and can be loaded by a variety of software, along with storing metadata (https://portal.hdfgroup.org)